# Qt checkable actions

Tags: c++, qt, button, action, signals

I'm making a rich text editor and I'm having trouble with my checkable actions. Right now I have:

```
void WordWriteMainWindow::on_actionItalic_toggled(bool arg1)
{
    if(arg1==true)
    {
        ui->textEdit->setFontItalic(true);
    }
    else
    {
        ui->textEdit->setFontItalic(false);
    }
}
```

For the most part it works. But, I want to make it so that the action is ONLY checked when you're about to type italics. Only specific things make the action checked while you're not writing in italics. Example: if you are typing normally and you click an area that is italic you will start typing in italics, but the action will be unchecked. Or if you highlight something and click italic, and then you click away to somewhere not italic it will be checked and you won't be typing in italics.

Do I need to use signals and slots? Or maybe some kind of if-else ladder? Thank you for the concern. I look forward to fixing this annoying issue. And look forward to many future road bumps because there will be a few when it comes to saving the file, etc.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code is is not terribly readable. Why not replace the "bool arg1" with something more descriptive like "bool enabled" or even "bool italic"? After that, you can also make the function a trivial one-liner:

```
void WordWriteMainWindow::on_actionItalic_toggled(bool italic)
{
    ui->textEdit->setFontItalic(italic);
}
```

Going to your actual question, yes, there has to be "something" which ties the action state back to what the `QTextEdit` thinks is currently active -- so far, you have specified just the coupling in the opposite direction. QTextEdit provides the [currentCharFormatChanged(const QTextCharFormat &)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#currentCharFormatChanged) signal which you can connect to. Connect another slot of yours into it and update the action checked state form it:

```
void WordWriteMainWindow::updateActionStateFromFormat(const QTextCharFormat &f)
{
    ui->yourItalicAction->setChecked(f.fontItalic());
}
```

You will have to connect that signal to your slot, of course. The easiest way is to add this to the constructor:

```
WordWriteMainWindow::WordWriteMainWindow()
{
    // your existing code goes here
    connect(ui->textEdit, SIGNAL(currentTextFormatChanged(QTextCharFormat)), 
                  this, SLOT(updateActionStateFromFormat(QTextCharFormat)));
}
```

Comment: Oh, okay. The first part was a good tip. Just seeing == true makes it easier for me to read, but the simplicity of this is much nicer. And I'm a little lost on the second part. I understand the concept of signals and slots, but I stopped using Qt for about 6 months and now I've forgotten how to use the signals and slots. What I do understand is that currentCharFormatChanged(const QTextCharFormat &) is supposed to send the signal and the next part is the slot, but how do I set up the signal exactly?

Comment: Mostly I just want to know how to use QTextCharFormat. And exactly what it is.

Comment: What do I put in the signal? void WordWriteMainWindow::currentCharFormatChanged(const QTextCharFormat &f)
{
    
}

Comment: I've been working on this for so long that my brain has stopped functioning. I want to get over this blockade before I take a break though.